# Writing huge longs array to disk

Tags: c#, arrays, binaryformatter

I need to write huge arrays of longs (up to 5GB) to disk.
I tried using `BinaryFormatter` but it seems to be able to write only arrays of size lower than 2GB:

```
long[] array = data.ToArray();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(dst, FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
try
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, array);
}
catch (SerializationException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    fs.Close();
}
```

This code throws `IndexOutOfRangeException` for larger arrays.

I don't want to save element per element, because it takes too much time.
Is there any proper way to save such large array?

Writing element per element:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(dst, FileMode.Create)))
{
    foreach(long v in array)
    {
        writer.Write(v);
    }
}
```

This is very slow.

Comment: You can now use very, very, very large arrays in .NET 4.5- ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MatthewMartin Yes, I know and I'm using. I have a problem with writing them to disk.

Comment: @Ari: How did you allocate it in the first place? Or do you have a lot of memory? I do have a solution and sample, but I cannot allocate 5GB at once (only 8GB of RAM). How many elements are in that array usually?

Comment: @MarcelN. I generated this data. Variable `data` is `List<long>`. There are up to `600 000 000` elements in these arrays.

Comment: @Ari: Yes, I managed to allocate it. I'm testing now. How much time do you get for individual writes? I have ~2.5 minutes for 3GB (on a 5400RPM external drive).

Comment: ...and make sure you're not writing to a FAT32 volume

Comment: In your writing per element how slow is very slow? And exactly how many elements are you writing? Also doing `long[] array = data.ToArray();` is going to take a lot of resources for a 3gb file, why don't you just do `foreach(long v in data)` or if possible never write to a `List<long>` at all and have whatever is creating these numbers write directly to your binary file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so maybe I got a little carried overboard with the MMF. Here's a simpler version, with a file stream only (I think this is what Scott Chamberlain suggested in the comments).

Timings (on a new system) for a 3Gb array:

1. MMF: ~50 seconds.
2. FilStream: ~30 seconds.

Code:

```
long dataLen = 402653184; //3gb represented in 8 byte chunks
long[] data = new long[dataLen];
int elementSize = sizeof(long);

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (FileStream f = new FileStream(@"D:\Test.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 32768))
{
    int offset = 0;
    int workBufferSize = 32768;
    byte[] workBuffer = new byte[workBufferSize];
    while (offset < dataLen)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, offset, workBuffer, 0, workBufferSize);
        f.Write(workBuffer, 0, workBufferSize);

        //advance in the source array
        offset += workBufferSize / elementSize;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

---

**Old solution, MMF**

I think you can try with a [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx). I got **~2 to ~2.5 minutes** for a 3Gb array on a relatively slower external drive.

What this solution implies:

1. First, create an empty file.
2. Create a memory mapped file over it, with a default capacity of X bytes, where X is the array length in bytes. This automatically sets the physical length of the file, on disk, to that value.
3. Dump the array to the file via a 32kx8 bytes wide accessor (you can change this, it's just something I tested with). So, I'm writing the array in chunks of 32k elements.

Note that you will need to account for the case when the array length is not a multiple of `chunkLength`. For testing purposes, in my sample it is :).

See below:

```
//Just create an empty file
FileStream f = File.Create(@"D:\Test.bin");
f.Close();

long dataLen = 402653184; //3gb represented in 8 byte chunks
long[] data = new long[dataLen];
int elementSize = sizeof (long);

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

//Open the file, with a default capacity. This allows you to write over the initial capacity of the file
using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"D:\Test.bin", FileMode.Open, "longarray", data.LongLength * elementSize))
{
    long offset = 0;
    int chunkLength = 32768; 

    while (offset < dataLen)
    {
        using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset * elementSize, chunkLength * elementSize))
        {
            for (long i = offset; i != offset + chunkLength; ++i)
            {
                accessor.Write(i - offset, data[i]);
            }
        }

        offset += chunkLength;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Sad that there is method `File.WriteAllBytes` and we can't use it, because we have `long[]` not `byte[]`. I expected something better from Microsoft. I think, `Buffer.BlockCopy` will be enought.

Comment: @Ari: But that would take away all the pleasure of writing lower level code.